# How can the RMI registry be stopped programatically?

Tags: java, rmi

I would like to stop the RMI registry programmatically. I thought this would be as trivial as calling some `stop()` or `shutdown()` method on classes `LocateRegistry` or `Naming` but there is no such method.

### Things I have tried

- I have tried to unregister all services and wait for the Registry's thread to end by itself gracefully, as proposed in some sites, but it does not seem to work (see #2 below).
- I have tried the recipe provided in [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386001/how-to-close-rmiregistry-running-on-particular-port) but although it stops the Registry the program as a whole does not stop (see #3 below).
- I have taken into account the answer provided in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22371487/clean-way-to-stop-rmi-server) and made sure that I unexport the actual result of creating the registry and not a stub (see #3 below).

### Code examples

1. If I have a trivial program that only creates the registry and does nothing else, it ends successfully.

   `// This is the only code in main()
    Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
    // reaches the end of main() and stops`
2. As soon as a service is registered, the Java Virtual Machine will not stop --- presumably because the Registry's has a thread running in the background. This would make sense if there were services registered but not so much if there are none (at least given the behaviour described above in #1):

   `// This is the only code in main()
    Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
    Naming.rebind("///name", new SomeRemoteServer());
    Naming.unbind("name");
    // never stops - must be killed with Ctrl-C`
3. At this point, it does not make any different if I try to unexport the Registry. The Registry is stopped (no more services can be registered to / unregistered from it) but the program continues running.

   `// This is the only code in main()
    Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
    Naming.rebind("///name", new EchoServer());
    Naming.unbind("name");
    if (registry != null) {
       UnicastRemoteObject.unexportObject(registry, true);
    }
    //
    // If executed, next line throws NoSuchObjectException
    // Naming.rebind("///name", new EchoServer()); 
    //
    // main program never stops - must be killed with Ctrl-C`

In short, the question is whether it is possible to stop the RMI Registry *programmatically* once (a) it has been created and (b) a service has been registered on it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have edited this question to make it explicit that it is not addressed by the solution to that other question.

Comment: You need to unexport all remote objects as well as the Registry. You don't need to unbind. There is a Java dot release somewhere in 1.5 that didn't stop the listening thread but that was many years ago. Duplicate.

Comment: "You need to unexport all remote objects as well as the Registry". Thank you very much, that was the missing piece. I think your comment deserves to be a answer as IMHO it was not very explicit in the documentation I have read or similar questions in SE. If you write that as an answer for future reference, I will select it. :-)

Comment: You're really asking a different question here. You *have* stopped the Registry. You haven't stopped the *JVM*, and that's because objects are still exported from it.